# Impersonate as a logged in Windows user without providing password c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, impersonation

I have hosted a web service which uploads the attachments on a specific physical server where the user has access. For Example:- If user1 logs in, it will upload the docs in  C:\Folders\user1(myattachements). If user2 logs in, it will upload the docs in C:\Folders\user2(myattachements). User1 will not have access to user2 path. Since my web service is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity, I need to impersonate as a logged in windows user. Is it possible to run the webservice under logged in Windows user without he providing his password. please help on this.. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Windows authentication? Impersonation enabled? All users can write to C:\Folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the identity that IIS uses for the application pool which is your best bet. OR you can give the ApplicationPoolIdentity access to the folder that you are trying to write files to.

Comment: Hi Matti - Thanks for your reply. It is a constraint that I do not have access to the IIS where the web service is hosted. So i need to impersonate as a logged in windows user while uploading docs. Please suggest if you have any alternate option for this..

Answer (score 0):

Web service is running under an application pool as it's hosted in IIS and this application pool runs under a particular identity. Identity user can be an admin user and can access server resources based on privileges. User1 or User2 are consumers of this web service. Access and privilege depends on ApplicationPoolIdentity, not on User1 or User2.

Comment: Hi Sudipta - Sorry my understanding might be wrong.. could you please tell me whether I can impersonate as a windows logged in user without asking his password...

Comment: No, you can't - it's a service and hosted in IIS, so all server resource access depends on ApplicationPoolIdentity. User1 or User2 are just a consumer and can't directly access anything in server.

Comment: I think you should have a different approach, build the folder path with user id (if available) while uploading the file and ApplicationPoolIdentity is  kinds of super user which can access all folders. User access privilege to be checked  while downloading the file.